# How do I query a Connected App's IP Relaxation settings?

Tags: managed-package, metadata-api, connected-apps

Within a connected app's manage settings page (Setup -> Managed Connected Apps, click on the Edit link next to the connected app of interest), you can see and set the OAuth Policies -> IP Relaxation settings:

[image: OAuth Policies -> IP Relaxation picklist values]

I've been digging around different Metadata Types, like [ConnectedApp](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm) and could use the MetadataService API to read that information. This `ConnectedApp` seems to show you nearly all connected app attributes except for this IP Relaxation setting.

Am I missing something here?  Is there a different Metadata Type that contains this information?  Or is there an existing object that we can SOQL into to see the current settings?

I know you can SOQL into `ConnectedApplication` and the `OptionsAllowAdminApprovedUsersOnly` field will tell you if the Permitted Users is set to "Admin Approved" (i.e. same as Metadata Type `ConnectedApp.isAdminApproved`), but I can't seem to find those IP Relaxation settings.

**Note**: I am trying to read this IP Relaxation setting in a subscriber org's managed package connected app.

Comment: Using the Salesforce Inspector Chrome extension and just looking through`ConnectedApplication`, I can see there's a field `OptionsIPRestrictions` and some other fields (`SessionPolicyAction`) that are greyed out (no details available) that I assume would contain what you're looking for. However, it doesn't appear to be something you can pull through the API

Comment: @KrisGoncalves That `OptionsIPRestrictions` slipped my radar, thank you for pointing it out! Strange that it's only a `boolean` value when there are 4 picklist values to choose from within the UI, and `SessionPolicyAction` is a `Picklist(1)` type meaning those picklist values are just one char long, probably indicating these four options

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to double check but it seems likely that this field corresponds to "ipRelaxation" under the "ConnectedAppOauthPolicy" category. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm