# What does ConnectedApp -> oauthConfig -> idTokenConfig represent?

Tags: metadata-api, connected-apps

Within the [ConnectedApp](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm) Metadata API, it has a setting nested under `oauthConfig` called `idTokenConfig`, of the type `ConnectedAppOauthIdToken`.

The `ConnectedAppOauthIdToken` class has five different fields:

1. `idTokenAudience`
2. `idTokenIncludeAttributes`
3. `idTokenIncludeCustomPerms`
4. `idTokenIncludeStandardClaims`
5. `idTokenValidity`

**Question**: Where do I see these settings on my connected app from within the Salesforce UI and where can I adjust them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID token (aka `id_token`) is issued in OpenID Connect(OIDC)-compliant flows. The token could contain *standard* claims (defined by OIDC spec) as well as *custom* claims. Out of the box, Salesforce supports two types of custom claims - claims based on SF profile permissions and claims based on User attributes. The former is represented by *Custom Permissions* checkbox in connected app UI and the latter is *Custom Claims*.

In addition to having the right params to trigger the flow, you have to explicitly configure the id token in the connected app. This is done by first selecting `Enable oAuth Settings` in the connected app and then selecting `Configure ID Token` in oAuth settings.

Comment: Thank you, really helpful to know.  This was all really just an attempt to get the IP Relaxation settings in the manage connected app settings. See this post [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/295159/how-do-i-query-a-connected-apps-ip-relaxation-settings) and would love your input if you have any ideas

Answer (score 0):

More details can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm)

***ConnectedAppOauthIdToken***

Specifies the ID token configuration for the connected app OAuth settings. Available in API version 43.0 and later.

[image]

Comment: This is what I linked and was referring to.  I want to know where do I see these settings for the connected app within the Salesforce UI